# C++ implementing derived class from base class by map and using methods from

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, abstract-class, implementation

i am facing issue which i want to create abstract class and 4 subclasses. Abstract class = Entry , and other subclasses are given in the code down.

```
class entry {
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const entry &obj);

private:
    static constexpr char *def_info = "Undefind";
protected:
    string desc;
    int ID;
    static int counter;
public:
    entry() : entry(def_info) {}

    entry(string input_s);

    void setDesc(string);

    string getDesc() const;

    int getID() const;

    virtual string getContents() const = 0;

    virtual void displaying(ostream &os) const = 0;

    virtual ~entry() = default;
};

int entry::counter = 0;

entry::entry(string input_s) :
        desc{input_s} {
    ++counter;
    ID = counter;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const entry &obj) {
    os << obj.getContents()<<endl;
    obj.displaying(os);
    return os;
}

void entry::setDesc(string input) {
    desc = input;
}

string entry::getDesc() const {
    return desc;
}

int entry::getID() const {
    return ID;
}

//PhoneEntry extending the Entry with a phone number
class phone_entry :virtual  public entry {
private:
    static constexpr char *text = "Undefind";
    static constexpr int def_no = 48000000000;
protected:
    int phone_number;
public:
    phone_entry(string input_s = text, int input = def_no) :
            entry(input_s), phone_number(input) {}

    virtual string getContents() const override {
        ostringstream output;
        output << "ID: " << ID << "\nD: " << desc << "\nPhone number : " << phone_number;
        return output.str();
    }

    virtual ~phone_entry() = default;
};

//EmailEntry extending the Entry with an e-mail addres
class email_entry : virtual public entry {
private:
    static constexpr char *def_info = "Undefind";

protected:
    string email;
public:
    email_entry(string des = def_info, string email_entry = def_info) :
            entry(des), email{email_entry} {}

    virtual string getContents() const override {
        ostringstream output;
        output << "ID: " << ID << "\nD: " << desc << "\nEmail : " << email;
        return output.str();
    }

    virtual ~email_entry() = default;
};
//AddressEntry extending the Entry with an address containing a city, a street and a house number

class address_entry : virtual public entry {
private:
    static constexpr char *def_info = "Undefind";
    static constexpr int def_no = 0;
protected:
    string city;
    string street;
    int house_number;

public:

    address_entry(string des = def_info, string c = def_info, string s = def_info, int hn = def_no) :
            entry{des}, city{c}, street{s}, house_number{hn} {}

    virtual string getContents() const override {
        ostringstream output;
        output << "ID: " << ID << "\nD: " << desc << "\nCity: " << city << "\nStreet: " << street << "\nHouse number: "
               << house_number;

        return output.str();
    }

    virtual ~address_entry() = default;
};

class contact_book : virtual public entry {
    static constexpr char *def_info = "Undefind";
private:
    map<string,entry *> contacts;
    string nick_name;
public:
    class error_mesg : public logic_error {
    public:
        error_mesg(const string message = "NULL") :
                logic_error(message) {}
    };

    contact_book(string e = "undefind") :
            entry{def_info},nick_name{e} {}

    void add(string a , entry &content){
        contacts.insert(make_pair(a,&content));
    }


    virtual void displaying(ostream &os) const override {
        os << "TESTING";
    }

};
```

I want to use contact_book class and use map container to insert the key and values to any of the subclasses like `("cool", new phone_entry("NAME",000000)` by using add method that it has two parameters one for the key and other it must have connection to the other classes so i thought that using entry obj will do the job ofc i used pointer in the member because i want to use Polymorphism. also i dont have any idea how i can use the getContencts and it knows from which subclass calling. For example , he asked that the main will look like this :

```
    ContactBook contacts(“My contacts”);
contacts.add(“Johny”, new PhoneEntry(“John Smith”, 100200300));
contacts.add(“Lisa”, new EmailEntry(“Lisa Wood”, “lisa@gmail.com”));
contacts.add(“Andy”, new AddressEntry(“Andrew Fox”, “Warsaw”, “Green St.”, 7));
cout << contacts;
//result (ordered):
//Andrew Fox: Warsaw, Green St. 7 (pos. 3)
//John Smith: phone 100200300 (pos. 1)
//Lisa Wood: e-mail lisa@gmail.com (pos. 2)
try {
 cout << contacts[“Andy”].getContents() << endl;
 //result:
 //Andrew Fox: Warsaw, Green St. 7 (pos. 3)
```

can you please help me out how to implement them and get what he wants and how & will work on that adding method and new as well in main func.

Comment: `entry(des), email{email_entry}` one can argue if uniform initialisation is a good thing or not (I strongly oppose against it...), but please - decide for one (consistently over entire file/project), don't mix...

Comment: Why would `contact_book` inherit from `entry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not pretty clear about what your actual problem is – so I'll assume you have trouble getting the desired output for the entire contact book...

First, some other issues, though:

It is meaningless to let `contact_book` inherit from `entry` - the book *contains* entries, it is not one. It seems as if you only inherited to be able to override `displaying` function to be able to use the already defined `operator<<` for `entry` class. But that's a bad reason for inheriting. Instead, you should provide a separate overload of `operator<<` for your contact book:

```
std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& s, contact_book const& cb); // coming to later
```

Then get used to reuse code where appropriate; I assume `getContents` should output the same string that would be written to `std::cout` via `operator<<`. OK, then let's profit from:

```
std::string entry::getContents()
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << *this;
    return s.str();
}
```

You don't need to have it virtual any more (and shouldn't).

I personally would go with a default for `displaying` function (that's not a very good name, though, you should prefer imperative forms 'display', perhaps even better: 'printToStream' or just 'printTo'):

```
void entry::printTo(std::ostream& s)
{
    // output members to s 
}
```

Then your inheriting classes could re-use it:

```
void phone_entry::printTo(std::ostream& s)
{
    entry::printTo(s); // use parent's version first to print common data
    // now append phone number to s... 
}
```

Users should rather use `operator<<` instead of `printTo` function, though. Might be a good idea to have it protected (or even private).

Finally getting back to outputting the contact book:

```
std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& s, contact_book const& cb)
{
    // you want to output every entry? then do so:
    for(auto& e : cb.contacts)
    {
        s << *e.second << std::endl;
        //     ^^^^^^^ map entries are of type std::pair<key_type const, mapped_type>
        //   ^ you stored pointers, operator<< accepts reference
    }
}
```

Again, you'd be re-using code already written.

One last note: You are mixing classic initialisation (parentheses) and uniform initialisation (braces), one time even in one single line (`email_contact`):

```
entry(des), email{email_entry}
```

I personally think UI *in general* has some valid reasoning, the way it was implemented in C++ is broken, though. There are quite a few other issues with, my 'favourite' one is:

```
std::vector<int> v0{7};   // gives you a vector with 7 elements, all 0!!!
// with classic initialization:
std::vector<int> v1(7);   // now clear, you WANT such a vector!
std::vector<int> v2({7}); // now clear, you want initializer list
```

You now can follow my reasoning or not (others opt *for* UI nonetheless to profit from the advantages of), but whatever you decide – please do it ***consistently*** over the entire file/project!